# Factor model eigenvalue inequality

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, statistics, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I do not understand how the inequality in Example 2.1 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.0175.pdf) is derived.

I do not understand the point in having:

$$-\lambda_{max}(\Sigma_u)$$

in the lower bound.

Using Weyl's inequality can we not get something better like:
$$\lambda_{max}(\Sigma) > Var(f_t) b^Tb + \lambda_{min}(\Sigma_u)$$